# GWT internationalization accent characters not displaying correctly

Tags: gwt, utf-8, internationalization

I have a few different languages in a gwt project.  For some reason the accent characters for locale_fr.properties works fine but the accent characters in locale_es.properties do not display correctly (show as "?" in a triangle).  The host html page is encoding using utf-8 as well as the project .xml file, so it doesn't seems like the issue is with what type of encoding I'm using.  Can't seem to figure out why the accent characters would work for one language but not another.  No difference in how the .properties files are set up from what I can tell...any suggestions on what could be causing this issue?

Comment: Are you sure that all `.properties` files are UTF-8 encoded?

Comment: I'm assuming they are since the host html page has charset set to utf-8 as well as the project .xml file...unless this is actually done for each specific .properties file, and if so I must be looking at the wrong place.  It does seem to work if, for example, i use Ã³ instead of ó.  Still doesn't make sense to me why I have a french .properties file using é and that is displaying fine...

Comment: Also, if I look at the source html when debugging i see the meta tag with charset=utf-8

Comment: Please, do check it when you're at work. Both meta charset and actual file encoding must match to display correctly. Up vote if my first guess was right :)

Comment: Looks like you were right Adam (i just misunderstood you at first)...I basically deleted the file (created a back up first), then changed the content type of the files in eclipse and re-added the locale .properties file.  Side note, if anyone is having this same issue you can change the content type in eclipse by going to window -> preferences -> general -> content types -> find your file type and set the default encoding and apply

Comment: Thanks for your help!